# How to check if file exist at FTP server in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In this app, I am using `FTP` server to download and upload images to the server. Now, I want to check if file exist at server. I would have the file name to check on the server. Currently, I am using `FTPManager` class to do all uploading and downloading. Its working fine. But I couldn't find any solution to check if file exist at server

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [this FTPManager class](https://github.com/nkreipke/FTPManager/blob/master/FTPManager/FTPManager.h), it seems to me like you should be able to create a new `FMServer` instance with the path to the folder you want, then call the manager's `-contentsOfServer:` method to get an array of dictionaries containing file information at that path.